# Is salary for march included in income tax if it gets paid in April?

Tags: income-tax, india

My mother is a pensioner in India. Her Pension for March 2019 was actually paid on 2nd April 2019.

My question is whether this amount would be considered as income for Assessment Year 2019-20  or Assessment Year 2020-21.

Comment: Why on earth would income paid in April 2019 even be considered as **2020-2021 income**? I can understand if the question was whether it should be declared as income on the 2018-2019 tax return (since the income was _for_ March 2019) or declared as income on the 2019-2020 tax return (albeit for 2018-2019 tax year), but why 2020-2021?

Comment: I had said assessment year - tax return of 2018-19 is Assessment year 2019-20 and taxt return of 2019-20 is Assessment year 2020-21

Answer (score -1):

It would be considered as March income. Assessment year 2019 to 2020